# Why can't I delete a remote branch in BitBucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch

When I try to do `git push origin :foo-branch'`, I get an error:

```
error: unable to delete 'foo-branch': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:username/repo-name.git'
```

I know the branch exist, because:

- I see it in `git log --all`;
- I see it in the web interface on BitBucket

What's more, even after I run `git remote prune origin`, I can still see it, when I run `git branch -a`:

`remote/origin/foo-branch`

I have also tried `git fetch -p origin` and still couldn't solve this problem.

Comment: did you try using 
    git push origin --delete branch

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Might it be a bitbucket quirk?

Comment: @tompave check that the remote you are trying to delete from is the correct one. I had several remotes and was trying to delete the branch from one of the remotes, which really didn't have it.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPopov, everything is correct.

Comment: I just bumped into the exact same problem: after `git push -d origin foo-branch`, it would still show up with `git branch -a`. `git fetch -p origin` fixed it for me, but you said you tried that and it didn't work for you.